Tic Tac Toe Basic C implementation

Is my implementation idiomatic?
Does it suffer from any undefined behaviour?

Any pointers/tips would be greatly appreciated.  Particularly, I think that the winner function could be improved.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* ascii values */
#define X 88
#define O 79

void print_board(char* b) {
    char buf[19] = {0};
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        buf[p++] = b[i] == 0 ? i + '1' : b[i];
        buf[p++] = (i + 1) % 3 == 0 ? '\n' : ' ';
    }
    printf("%s", buf);
}

/* 0 is ongoing; 1 is draw. */
char winner(char* b) {
    char pieces[2] = {X, O};
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        char p = pieces[i];
        if (/* rows */
            b[0] == p && b[1] == p && b[2] == p ||
            b[3] == p && b[4] == p && b[5] == p ||
            b[6] == p && b[7] == p && b[8] == p ||
            /* cols */
            b[0] == p && b[3] == p && b[6] == p ||
            b[1] == p && b[4] == p && b[7] == p ||
            b[2] == p && b[5] == p && b[8] == p ||
            /* diagonals */
            b[0] == p && b[4] == p && b[8] == p ||
            b[2] == p && b[4] == p && b[6] == p)
            return p;
    }
    for (int i=0; i < 9; i++)
        if (b[i] == 0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

char getmove(char player, char* b) {
    char c;
    int ok = 0;
    do {
        printf("%c to move: ", player);
        for (c = getchar(); getchar() != '\n';)
            ;
        putchar('\n');
        if (c < '0' || c > '9')
            printf("Expected a number 0-9\n");
        else if (b[c - '0' - 1])
            printf("Square %c is taken\n", c);
        else
            ok = 1;
    } while (!ok);
    return c - '1';
}

void makemove(char player, int pos, char* b) {
    assert(pos >= 0 && pos < 9);
    b[pos] = player;
}

void print_winner(char result) {
    assert(result);
    if (result == 1)
        printf("It's a draw!\n");
    else
        printf("%c wins!\n", result);
}

int main(void) {
    char player = X;
    char move;
    char board[9] = {0};
    int status;
    while (!(status = winner(board))) {
        print_board(board);
        move = getmove(player, board);
        makemove(player, move, board);
        player = player == X ? O : X;
    }
    print_board(board);
    print_winner(status);
    return 0;
}


getchar() returns an int, not a char:

Defined in header <stdio.h>
int getchar( void );
Reads the next character from stdin.
Equivalent to getc(stdin).

See: Difference between int and char in getchar/fgetc and putchar/fputc?.
Eliminate magic values from the code:
/* ascii values */
#define X 88
#define O 79

But what do 88 and 79 signify? Why not define an enum instead?
char buf[19] = {0};

Why 19? This would be better as:
#define BOARD_SIZE 19

// Or, C24 and above
constexpr unsigned int board_size = 19; // Or deduce the type with auto

Similarly, I see the naked value 9 being repeated multiple times. It should be some named constant as well.
Similarly, define some named constants for "draw" and "ongoing" instead of using 0 and 1.
Only declare variables where required:
move = getmove(player, board);
makemove(player, move, board);

We don't need move here. Simply do:
makemove(player, getmove(player, board), board);

Prefer using standard exit status codes instead of magic values:
stdlib.h defines EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE. return 0 is better as return EXIT_SUCCESS.
Simplify:
void print_winner(char result) {
    assert(result);
    if (result == 1)
        printf("It's a draw!\n");
    else
        printf("%c wins!\n", result);
}

can be written as:
void print_winner(char result) {
    assert(result);
    printf(result == 1 ? "It's a draw!\n" : "%c wins!\n", result);
}

In winner() (this could be named better):
for (int i=0; i < 9; i++)
        if (b[i] == 0)
            return 0;
return 1;

can be replaced with:
#include <string.h>

return memchr(b, 0, 9) != NULL;

Error messages go to stderr:
if (c < '0' || c > '9')
    printf("Expected a number 0-9\n");
else if (b[c - '0' - 1])
    printf("Square %c is taken\n", c);

Assuming these are actually errors, they should be going to stderr (with fputs()/fprintf()) instead of stdout.
Use const for data that is not modified:
In print_board(), winner(), and getmove(), b is not modified anywhere in the code. So it should be declared with the const qualifier.
b should also be named appropriately. It would be better as board.
Also note that char* b is C++ style. C style is char *b.
Use puts() where appropriate:
printf("%s", buf);

We do not require printf()'s formatting capabilities here, so puts() would be more appropriate to use here, even if most compilers would make that switch for you automatically.

This is great feedback, lots of useful tips here which I didn't know about at all. It's great to see how many improvements can be made in even a very small program. Thanks for taking the time to review it :)

I didn't know we can use a ternary like that in printf, that's cool.

@wed1may Welcome to C, I look forward to seeing more of your questions.
